# Converting from char to int

Tags: java, char, int

I am trying to apply binary search on a string which contains integers. This is my code

```
public class abcd {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String num="";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        num += input.next();
    }
    if(bs(5,num))
        System.out.println("Yep");
    else
        System.out.println("Nope");
}
public static boolean bs(int key,String N){
    int low=0,high=N.length()-1,mid;
    while(high>=low){
        mid = (high+low)/2;
        if(N.charAt(mid) == key)
            return true;
        else if(N.charAt(mid) < key)
            low = mid+1;
        else
            high = low-1;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

bs is the binary search method.My input is already sorted. Now I wish to find if 5 was entered but even if 5 is included as input, I always get "Nope" as output which implies that bs always returns false.

I understand that charAt returns a char and so that is where the problem is. But then if I wish to convert that char to an int, what should I do?
For example, how do I convert '4' to 4?

Comment: strings don't contain integers. They might contain digits...Also, more importantly, binary search only works on sorted sets...

Comment: @MitchWheat I am giving sorted input

Comment: where does it state that in your question? No-where....

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention i'll edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are trying to compare chars with ints which wont work.  How about only using chars?

```
public static boolean bs(char key,String N){
```

and call

```
bs('5', '25789');
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert your key to a char first by using [Character.forDigit()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#forDigit-int-int-)

```
public static boolean bs(int intkey,String N){
    char key = Character.forDigit(intkey,10);

    int low=0,high=N.length()-1,mid;
    //...
    //the rest of your function should stay the same
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
int intValue = N.charAt(mid) - 0x30;
```

Or

```
int intValue = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(N.charAt(mid)));
```